# Trying to "thin" a car body and make panels more smooth

Tags: modeling, vertices, polycount

Im honestly stuck, and still somewhat new to blender ive exhausted all my options. I have a car body in blender that comes from slot car racings so its 3d printed but is going into a game now. Ive gotten most of the body panels pretty smooth from subdividing and lowering the poly count a little but it is still looking bad. The other problem I have is not being able to make the body panels thinner because of the vertices. All of the cars ive worked on were completely different and had about 1/100 as many faces and made it easy to just select certain parts. Any help is appreciated. [image][image][image]

Comment: tbh the geometry is a mess. I would recommend to remodel it with quads.

Comment: If your model is composed of triangles and ngons, subdividing it will only make it worse. Try using an addon to remesh it with quads like Quadremesher for example, or do it manually. As for the thickness of the panels, I would recomand deleting it and using a solidify modifier instead

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options

- The first one is super simple if you don't want to put much work into it. Simply <kbd>Right Click</kbd> on your model, then at the top, just below *Edit Sketch* hit *Shade Smooth*, from there go into your object Data properties (the little green triangle), on the *Properties Window*, then look for the *Normals* tab. Open it and hit *Auto Smooth*. This will fix any shading errors that may occur.
- For the second and longer option. at the top, hit *Add* and add in a *Plane* make sure it is centered on your car, then split it in half and delete the left side. from there, go to your *Modifiers* tab (the blue wrench) on the *Properties Window*. Hit *Add Modifier* and add a *Mirror Modifier* you'll also want to add in a *Shrink-Wrap Modifier*, these will allow you to only work on one side while it copy's to the other, as well as keep your new mesh right on the surface of your model

[image]

From there you can fully retopologize your model exactly the way you want using  <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude more faces from the first one.